Is it valid to learn geometric algebra?
I saw a few people say they recommend to learn geometric algebra.
Since I have only finished Apostol's calculus, I do not have ability to evaluate this subject properly.
To be honest, I feel it seems cool but I don't like the lack of rigor. I thought I was confident to say it is ok to start learning now, since it has been many years after it exists.
But after I see this https://terathon.com/blog/poor-foundations-ga.html , named Poor Foundations of Geometric Algebra by Lengyel, who has been studying GA for 15 years, I end up losing my confidence to start learning GA.
Author mainly criticizes many popular GA books(mainly Leo Dorst's GA for computer scientists, Macdonald's book which deemed as a standard book nowadays and Lounesto's book which is more rigorous and so on...) on Inner Product and Hodge dual, which are fundamental parts of GA. Well, he does not mention Macdonald's book directly in this link, but he criticizes Def 6.15, 6.23 of inner product and page 111 on hodge dual as well.
I hope to know if there exists a way to learn GA rigorously. If it is impossible, I would make a plan to learn standard clifford algebra as quotient of tensor algebra.

Clifford algebras are perfectly rigorous pieces of mathematics. What can happen is that since they are sometimes used in more applied fields of mathematics, they are also taught in perhaps less rigorous textbooks. My personal advice would be to avoid texts that refer to it as "geometric algebra" if you want a more algebraic treatment. This is not the terminology used by experts in algebra and quadratic form theory. But then maybe you won't find the material you want, if you're looking for something which is focused on euclidean geometry.

@CaptainLama ty for you advice, since i'm undergraduate student on physics, i dont know what learning path i have to follow. since it seems clifford algebra does very strongly encompass almost all physics.

I agree with @CaptainLama. For some reason, some authors like to use the term geometric algebra and start using different notations and what not. However, both Clifford algebra theory (and related theory of exterior algebras) are very well founded and very active and important throughout mathematics and physics.

No.  It's a misnomer.

Playing something like devil's advocate, even if writings on "Geometric Algebra" were the only way to get certain deep intuitions about some things in physics, that's not likely the approach your teachers and textbooks are likely to use and you might gain other intuitions from other approaches. So even when we stack the deck for GA in this way, I'd still recommend reading GA texts after you have learned more standard treatments of relevant physics like the electromagnetic four-potential and quantum mechanics.

The article you linked to by Lengyel (as far as I can tell from skimming) makes some valid criticisms of a specific textbook, but he also has very much decided that his conventions and notations are The One True Way, and the tone he takes in writing this article is appalling. I would say that you should ignore this article entirely. This article aside, I have never liked anything I've seen from Lengyel and I think there are (ironically) fundamental issues in the way he approaches PGA (more so pedagogically rather than as an issue of mathematical rigour).

GA is very much a "rigourous" subject; it's just a certain view on real Clifford algebras. However, I don't think there is any good, in depth text on every aspect of GA, and many texts will probably require a certain amount of mathematical maturity anyway because this just isn't a subject that is usually taught in a class anywhere. I could rattle off a bibliography that covers many, many different topics and viewpoints, but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

My understanding is that Macdonald's text would be the best option available to you, but (1) I haven't really read it, and (2) I believe it only covers Euclidean GA.

@NicholasTodoroff thank you for your kind advice. i had read your activities in this community about this subject and think you are an expert on GA&Clifford. Student(like me) considering this subject  needs any advices to make a learning path. i had seen you start learning GA with a book named GA for physicists somewhere(maybe your LinkedIn). it would be nice if you teach me... i really need any helps since i want to co-study standard traditional books with GA books...

Geometric Algebra for Physicists by Doran and Lasenby is a great book, but it is not written "from the ground-up". While it serves well as an introduction to GA, you need to be familiar already with the physics that it covers to be able to tackle those sections effectively.

An important question is why do you want to study GA? This makes a significant difference in the path I would recommend. For instance, if you're interested in GA in physics and you're just now wrapping up an introduction to one-variable calculus, I think I can say confidently that you need to study physics more before looking at GA approaches. If you're interested in studying GA for its own sake, as pure mathematics, then I would suggest you first get comfortable with basic topics in multilinear algebra; and before that with linear algebra in abstract, not just as the study of matrices.

@NicholasTodoroff the reason why i want to learn GA is to get used to Clifford algebra in the future. As a physics student, i want to learn Clifford algebra for fermions and Symplectic clifford algebra for bosons. For the latter case, i really don't know anything but it seems it requires strong mathematical maturities... so i think i need to start traditional books for sure and with GA for companions.

@NicholasTodoroff but as you already said, i would study tranditional physics surely first!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Contrary to what Lengyel claims, Dorst et al.'s defintions of scalar products and contractions are mathematically justified: they arise from the exclusive use of the twisting symmetry on the category of graded modules, as done for example in Chapter 4 and onward of Helmsletter and Micali's book Quadratic Mappings and Clifford Algebras. By contrast, Lengyel's definitions arise from an additional use of the ordinary symmetry on the category of graded modules.
Moreover, there is no error in Dorst et al.'s (or Lounesto's) assertion that $a\rfloor(B\wedge C)=a\rfloor B+(-1)^{\deg B}B\wedge(a\rfloor C)$. Lengyel contradicts himself when claiming there is such a mistake: he claims that  $(B\wedge C)\lfloor a=B\lfloor a+(-1)^{\deg B}\wedge(C\lfloor a)$ is correct in his notation, but the right contraction $B\lfloor A$ in his notation is the same as the standard left contraction $\tilde A\rfloor B$ with the reverse $\tilde A$ of $A$. In particular, the two identities are the same (and in fact both correct).
Finally, there is a mathematical basis for having contractions given by components of the geometric product, namely the the theory of deformations of Clifford algebras, which is worked out in full detail in Helmsletter and Micali's book. For Lengyel to claim otherwise is to ignore the larger algebraic context of geometric algebras.
Lengyel does have a point in that there is another inner product on the exterior algebra in addition to the scalar product of the geometric algebra. Consequently, taking the scalar product, or the other inner product, with a pseudoscalar results in two different dualities on the geometric algebra. Only the latter seems to have good geometric properties, matching the Hodge dual of exterior algebra.
I am inclined to agree with Lengyel that the absence of this inner product and corresponding correct expression of Hodge duality is a gap in the foundations of geometric algebra limting its proper geometric use. However, the existing foundations concerning the scalar product and contractions are not poor, but part of the larger algebraic context of Clifford algerbas.
Regarding Dorst et al.'s claims on transform composition and projective geometric algebra, Lengyel may be correct but I do not know to evaluate those claims.

In more detail on how Lengyel's definitions arise from using ordinary instead of twisting symmetry, recall that the twisting symmetry $A\otimes B\to B\otimes A$ on graded modules is given by mapping homogeneous elements according to $a\otimes b\mapsto(-1)^{\deg a\deg b}b\otimes a$, whereas the ordinary symmetry is given by $a\otimes b\mapsto b\otimes a$. Their composite is the twisting action on tensor products given by $a\otimes b\mapsto(-1)^{\deg a\deg b}a\otimes b$. Consequently, any graded algebra structure given by $A\otimes A\to A$ (or graded coalgebra structure given by $A\to A\otimes A$) determines three additonal graded (co)algebra structures: the opposite, twisted, and twisted opposite obtained by composing with the symmetry, twist, or twisted symmetry of tensor products.
Now, any bilinear form on a module $M$, when identified with a linear map $b\colon M\to M^*$ to its dual $M^*$, induces a bilinear form on its exterior algebra $\Lambda M$ that vanishes on elements of different degrees, and corresponds to the unique algebra homomorphism $\Lambda M\to(\Lambda M)^*$ extending the linear composite $M\to M^*\to \Lambda^* M$ to the graded algebra $\Lambda^* M$ of alternating maps on $M$. Such an extension exists (and is unique) because the algebra structure on $\Lambda ^*M$ guarantees $(m^*)^2=0$ for any image $m^*\in(\Lambda M)^*$ of $m\in M$ under that linear composite.
Explicitly, the algebra structure on $(\Lambda M)^*$ is given by $(f\wedge g)(m_1\wedge\cdots\wedge m_n)=\sum_s\DeclareMathOperator\sgn{sgn}\sgn(s)f(m_{s(1)},\dots, m_{s(i)})g(m_{s(i+1)}),\dots,g(m_{s(n)})$ where $f$ is an $i$-form, $g$ an $n-i$-form, $m_i\in M$, and $s$ ranges over permutations satisfying $s(1)<\cdots<s(i)$ and $s(i+1)<\cdots<s(n)$, and $\sgn(s)$ is the sign of the permutation. It follows that the induced bilinear form on $\Lambda M$ is given by $b(m_1\wedge,\cdots,\wedge m_n,m'_1\wedge\cdots m'_n)=\det(b(m_i,m'_j))$. Applied to an inner product on $M$, this induces Lengyel's preferred inner product on $\Lambda M$.
But $(m^*)^2=0$ in $\Lambda^*M$ implies $(m^*)^2=0$ also for the opposite, twisted, and twisted opposite algebra structures on $\Lambda^*M$. Thus, there are a priori another three induced bilinear forms on $\Lambda M$. Fortunately, $\Lambda^*M$ is twisted commutative, i.e. is the same as its twisted opposite, i.e. its opposite is the same as its twist. So there is one other bilinear form induced by the opposite algebra $\Lambda^\wedge M$ given by $b^\wedge(m_1\wedge\cdots\wedge m_n,m'_1\wedge\cdots\wedge m'_n)=\det(b(m_{n-i},m'_j))=(-1)^{n\choose2}B(m_1\wedge\cdots\wedge m_n,m'_1\wedge\cdots\wedge m'_n)$. Applied to an inner product on $M$, the inner product induced in this way is the scalar product of the correponding Clifford algebra.

The twisting symmetry first arises because of the fundamental result that the Clifford algebra $\DeclareMathOperator\Cl{Cl}\Cl((M,q)\perp(M',q'))$ of an orthogonal sum $(M,q)\perp(M',q')=(M\oplus M',q+q')$ of quadratic modules is the twisted tensor product $\Cl(M,q)\hat\otimes\Cl(M',q')$ of the Clifford algebras of those quadratic modules.
The diagonal map $M\to M\oplus M$ underlies morhpisms of quadratic modules $(M,q)\to(M,0)\perp(M,q)$ and $(M,q)\to(M,q)\perp(M,0)$, making $(M,0)$ into a cocommutative coalgebra over which $(M,q)$ has compatible left and right comodule structures. Consequently, the exterior algebra $\Lambda M=\Cl(M,0)$ is a cocommutative coalgebra in the category of graded algebras with twisted tensor product over which each Clifford $\Cl(M,q)$ algebra has compatible left and right comodule structures.
Now on the one hand, the dual $A^*$ of a graded module $A$ admits two morphisms $A^*\otimes A^*\to(A\otimes A)^*$ that are twists of one another. Each arises from following the ordinary or twisted symmetry $A^*\otimes A^*\otimes A\otimes A\to A^*\otimes A\otimes A^*\otimes A$ with the product of evaluation maps from $A^*\otimes A$. Call the former the ordinary morphism $A^*\otimes A^*\to(A\otimes A)^*$ and the latter the twisted morphism.
On the other hand, when $A\to A\otimes A$ is a coalgebra structure on $A$, the composition of $A^*\otimes A^*\to(A\otimes A)^*\to A^*$ is an algebra structure on $A^*$. Moreover, the opposite, twisted, and twisted oposite coalgebra structures on $A$ lead to the opposite, twisted, and twisted opposite algebra structures on $A^*$. Thus if $A\to A\otimes A$ is twisted cocommutative, then $A^*\otimes A^*\to A^*$ is also twisted commutative, so that its opposite and twisted structures are the same.
It follows that the twisted algebra structure on $\Lambda^*M$ arises from using the coalgebra structure on $\Lambda M$ and the twisted morphism $(\Lambda M)^*\otimes(\Lambda M)^*\to(\Lambda M\otimes\Lambda M)^*$.
Since $\Cl(M,q)$ is compatibly a left and right comodule over $\Lambda M$, it is also a bimodule over the algebra $\Lambda^*M$. Composing with the algebra homomorphisms $\Lambda M\to\Lambda^*M$, one obtains two structures of $\Cl(M,q)$ as a $\Lambda M$-bimodule, depending on whether $\Lambda^*M$ was given the ordinary or twisted algebra structure. The one arising from the twisted algebra structure consists of the left and right contractions defined by Dorst et al. The one arising from the ordinary one consists of Lengyel's left and right contractions.
Finally, since the twisted algebra structure is simply the opposite one, the two $\Lambda M$-bimodule structures on $\Cl(M,q)$ are canonical related by being opposite to one another, which explains why Lengyel's right contraction is given by Dorst et al.'s left contraction with a reversed element.

wow thank you so much! I feel this answer is a gem!

It seems, in summary, 1. the existing foundations concerning the scalar product and contractions are not poor, but part of the larger algebraic context of Clifford algerbas. 2. Only Lengyel's inner product seems to have good geometric properties, matching the Hodge dual of exterior algebra.

"Is it valid to learn geometric algebra?" Answer: Yes!
You write: "I feel it seems cool but I don't like the lack of rigor. If it is impossible, I would make a plan to learn standard Clifford algebra as quotient of tensor algebra."
There is no need for this: my geometric algebra book is rigorous, more so than others I think, because it is a mathematics text. Yet it has no mathematical prerequisites beyond high school algebra. (And an ability to follow a mathematical argument, which might need to be gained from a calculus course.) There is no reliance on the tensor or exterior algebras.
You write: "He does not mention Macdonald's book directly in this link, but he criticizes Def 6.15, 6.23 of inner product."
Lengyel writes: "An inner product must produce a scalar quantity by definition." Must? Why? If more general objects go into a function, why can't more general objects come out? To me, the only "must" for the geometric algebra inner product is that it reduces to the standard inner product of inner product spaces - otherwise the naming is confusing. Geometric algebra's several choices for the inner product do this.
Lengyal: "There is a religious belief that the geometric product is fundamental and that all other products should be derived from it." Yes, that is the belief of advocates of GA, precisely because all other products can be derived from the geometric product. That is what makes it fundamental. ("Religious" is part of the "appalling tone" mentioned by Nicholas Todoroff.)
Dorst's "The Inner Products of Geometric Algebra" defends his choice of the fundamental inner product. It persuaded me.
Lengyal keeps relying on exterior algebra for justification of his geometric algebra definitions, as if exterior algebra was not only historically prior to geometric algebra but also logically prior. Geometric Algebra can stand on its own with no input from exterior algebra. In fact the exterior algebra can be defined in terms of geometric algebra. As far as I know, the reverse is not possible.
By all means study physics at the same time, but there is no reason to delay geometric algebra.

Thank you so much professor! I really didn't expect the author of a popular books to answer my question so that i didn't write down a detail of the criticism. I trust your book. But because of the fact that it is not a standard subject yet, I just wanted to get confirmation before i started studying.

Here is Lengyel's criticism on your book: I think Macdonald's book is very concise and clean compared to others but it does have some of the same issues that i wrote about in my post. In particular, Definition 6.15 gives one of the problematic definitions of the inner product, and Definition 6.23 gives the same broken definition of dual that has an inconsistent orientation and fails to extend to the degenerate metrics of projective algebras. Has also says, at the bottom of page 111, that the Hodge dual can't be defined directly in the exterior algebra, which is not correct.

I have found this paper: Charles Gunn, A bit better: Variants of duality in geometric algebras with degenerate metrics. In summary, although i don't know this subject well, it seems it supports that your book has no errors in general and that Lengyel's criticism is also valid in special case. But Lengyel's representation seems a bit complicated. To overcome degenerate metrics cases, it seems this paper proposes "Geometric Dual".

When you wrote "the Hodge dual can't be defined directly in the exterior algebra, which is not correct" do you mean "geometric algebra"?
Yengyel's first criticism here, about my inner product, was addressed in my previous post. If my criticism there is accepted, then Yengyel's other criticism's of geometric algebra's inner product are moot. For example, my inner product is always real and positive indefinite, thus so is the norm of a multivector.

If it is Lengyel vs. Gunn, I choose Gunn. Yengyel again seems scattershot, with no overarching principles. What works for him is right. I think that Gunn is under appreciated. He is steeped in the history of these ideas from the 18th century. Not only does he advocate for PGA, he explains its inevitability, given motivated principles that he sets out. That is what his paper "Geometric algebras for euclidean geometry" is about. Have a look.

I'm now going to bow out of this conversation. Except for my books, which I update now and then, I've also bowed out of geometric algebra to concentrate on physics.

Thank you for your kind reply! Since english is not my first language, i would apologize if there existed any uncomfortable words. You make me convince to start learning GA. As a physics undergraduate student, i'm really happy to get some direct reply from a professor.

I see the first part of your message: "Dear professor, i tried to buy your book named Vector and Geometric calculus, but it seems almost", but no more, so I don't know how to reply exactly. Maybe the address of my book at Amazon will help: https://www.amazon.com/dp/1480132454
Please reply so I know what's up.

Thank you for the reply professor! I had lost what i wrote "Dear Professor ~" . But i remember it is just a message that belongs to my concern that i thought all of the very book has been sold out. I deleted a message because I felt like I was bothering the professor, but it looks like the news was left behind. That is, i hoped to know if this book keeps getting any updates or publishing. It seems only a few copies remain. best regards

There will be no more updates this year. I think that the book will be available duding that time.

Thank you professor!

@AlanMacdonald Lengyel's comment on your book is from https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=41374480 . Stripped of the polemics, Lengyal's arguement is for the scalar product being the grade zero component of the geometric product with one input reversed and the Hodge dual being the geometric product of the pseudoscalar with the other input reversed.  The argument is that with these conventions, the natural bijection with the exterior algebra is a homomorphism also for the inner product and Hodge structures that the latter acquires naturally from the inner product on the vector space.

@AlanMacdonald regarding the interdefinability of geometric algebra and exeterior algebra, I believe Fauser and Ablamowicz's paper On the Decomposition of Clifford Algebras of Arbitrary Bilinear Form shows that there are many different inequivalent gradings (one for each antisymmetric form) one can endow the Clifford algebra with. This seems to run counter to your claim that the geometric algebra can stand on its own without the exterior algebra.

@VladimirSotirov GA represents geometric objects and operations in R^n with algebraic objects and operations in the geometric algebra G^n. The bijection is irrelevant.
Definitions of the geometric, inner (not Lengyel's), and outer products of GA give dimension agnostic GA formulas for projections, rotations, and reflections in R^n. There are unifications "geometric product = inner product + outer product" and "gradient = divergence + curl", with generalized divergence and curl. The fundamental theorem of geometric calculus generalizes and unifies the integral theorems of vector calculus.

@VladimirSotirov GA has no need for interdefinability because it has no need for exterior algebra. My books on geometric algebra and calculus make no use of exterior algebra. They stand on their own.
Lengyel is an expert on exterior algebra and wants GA to be an extension of it. He does this by insisting that the GA community's agreed upon and fertile inner product is wrong!! From the perspective of GA it is better to define exterior operations in terms of GA operations. A paper of Professor Michael Taylor does this for the Hodge dual. He will post it soon and I will report that here.

@VladimirSotirov Please elaborate on your comment that the Fauser and Ablamowicz paper "seems to run counter to your claim that the geometric algebra can stand on its own without the exterior algebra". I have no idea what you mean.

@VladimirSotirov Here is a link to Taylor's Hodge Star paper. https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6t0kzhaw86o2kiowghjvm/Hodge_Star.pdf

@AlanMacdonald to elaborate as requested: The exterior algebra is the associated graded algebra of the filtration induced by the choice of generators (grade $1$ elements) of the geometric algebra. Ablamowicz and Fauser's result implies that each alternating bilinear form determines another distinct choice of generators, and hence of grading. So usage of grading is usage of the exterior algebra (even if the term is not mentioned), and its construction depends not only on the geometric product, but also on the choice of generators.

@VladimirSotirov Thank you for responding. Hestenes defines geometric algebra as Clifford algebra with a geometric interpretation. I accept this, so mathematically we are talking about Clifford algebras. I still don't fully understand your point, but I think that you are saying that there is no unique choice for Clifford algebra. This is true.
But given natural numbers p,q (0 allowed), there is a unique Clifford algebra G^{p,q} (Lounesto, Clifford Algebras and Spinors, p. 190). This allows other GA's, like the conformal model and PGA, with indefinite metrics.

There is a similar statement at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra, under the heading Real numbers.

@AlanMacdonald Yes, we are mathematically talking about Clifford algebras. Of course different quadratic forms give different Clifford algebras which can have different geometric interpretations. My point is that the extension of the parity $\mathbb Z/2$-grading of a Clifford algebra to a $\mathbb N$-indexed grade decomposition should also be considered part of that geometric interpretation. For any bilinear form $\beta$ with associated quadratic form $q(m)=\beta(m,m)$, there is such a decomposition of the Clifford algebra of $q$ for which $\beta$ is the scalar product, for example.

Namely, the $\mathbb Z/2$-isomorphism of the Clifford algebra of $q$ to the exterior algebra deformed by $\beta$, as described in Chapter 4 section 8 of Helmsletter and Micali's book Quadratic Mappings and Clifford Algebras. So assuming a grade-decomposition in which the scalar product is symmetric (on grade $1$) is tantamount to picking a particular isomorphism with the exterior algebra.

@Vladimir Sotirov Sorry that I dropped the ball; I haven't wanted to take the time to learn the mathematics necessary to understand your last post. But maybe you could close our thread by stating advantages of your approach for someone who simply wants to learn GA to use it as a tool.

Your question is a bit multi-faceted and has received answers from some angles, but I'd like to cover another one.
If your intuition is that geometric algebra is a field in flux with many active debates being held about the best ways of doing things, then I'd say it's guilty as charged.
Whether that means you should or shouldn't study it, all comes down to your preferences. If your interest goes out to the study of the most settled mathematics, you have your answer. If you feel challenged to be the person to reformulate ga in a way that will settle such debates once and for all; then there is your answer. It's not for a lack of validity and interestingness of the core ideas of ga that you need to stay away from it.
Similarly, someone mentioned in the comments above that for the purposes of physics it's best to study other formalisms first, since they are much more used. If your goal is to recite what other physicists have done before you, that is of course exactly right.
